# C++ CreateProcess() Runs In The Same Window As The First One

Tags: c++

I'm using `CreateProcess()` from a **console** program to run another **console** program, but it runs **in the same window** as the first one.

```
STARTUPINFO sinfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;

LPSTR commandLine = " \"Cows and Bulls.exe\" test ";

ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(sinfo));
ZeroMemory(&pinfo, sizeof(pinfo));

if(!CreateProcess(0,commandLine, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, &sinfo, &pinfo))
    cout << "failed";
```

This is my code. What am I doing wrong? It gets really fun when I add a

```
for(int i=0; true; i++)
{
    cout << i;
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

to the first one. Then it starts outputting the numbers **IN** the next one.

It's like the two programs are **merged**.. I don't want that, i want to open a **new** window.

P.S. I'm passing arguments, yes, but if I cut the `test` the result's the same.

Comment: How did that succeed? You didn't set `sInfo.cb`.

Comment: @chris I had it set `sinfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);` then I made it a comment to see if it's going to work and it did.

Comment: Hmm, I don't recall `CreateProcess` ever working when I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give the child process a new console you need to set the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag in the `dwCreationFlags` argument of your call to `CreateProcess`. Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ah, I saw it in some of the examples but never tried it. Thanks!